# erros de rotas no laravel

Tags: laravel

tenho um formulario e defini o method como POST

```
                        <form id="formulario_de_login" method="post" action="/auth">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email_login" class="search input_email_login form-control" id="exampleInputEmail12" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Senha</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password_login" class="search input_senha_login form-control" id="exampleInputPassword12">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-danger" id="erros_login"></p>
                        <button type="button" id="confirmar_login" onclick="location.href = '/auth'" class="btn">Entrar</button>
                    </form>
```

na minha rota tambem esta definido como post

```
Route::post('/auth', [UserController::class, 'auth']);
```

e no meu controlador so queria exibir os valores vindo do formulario

```
public function auth(Request $request) {

    echo $request->email_login;
    echo $request->password_login;

}
```

mas está dando erro 405 method not allowed, por algum motivo a minha requisição está indo via get mesmo definindo como post

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

O botão do seu formulário está desta forma:

```
<button type="button" id="confirmar_login" onclick="location.href = '/auth'" class="btn">Entrar</button>
```

Ele tem um evento onclick que está direcionando por GET para /auth.

Como a rota para este endereço é do tipo POST, existem duas formas de resolver, a primeira é você retirar este button e inserir um input do tipo submit

```
<input type="submit" value="Entrar">
```

Ou então você remove o onclick deste button e altera o tipo de button

```
<button type="submit">Entrar</button>
```